# Is the admob tracking methods safe to use on iOS?

Tags: ios, app-store, admob, analytics, uuid

I want to somehow know when a user has pressed an ad from admob and know if an app download from the app-store came from an click on an ad.

In the documentation for admob about this on this link:
http://support.google.com/admob/bin/answer.py?hl=en&topic=1623717&answer=1704628

it says that this might violate Apples ruling about collecting UUID, is any of the methods acceptable to use?, or is there a chance to get rejected by Apple for using them?

Is there any way of tracking a click to a download at all on from the app-store?

Comment: Did you find an answer for that by now?

Comment: Not a solution other than it's not possible.